# CSS Grid is being vertical

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm new to CSS Grid and I want to create a grid of divs. I want the grids to be fill up horizontally--filling up the pink div, but instead they go vertical like in the snippet below. I've tried everything, how do I fix it

```css
.mygrid
{
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  gap: 2px;
  grid-template-columns: 30px 40px;
}

.item
{
 
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have constrained the grid to two columns. What do you actually want?

Answer (score 0):

You should define the columns to half and half, using the "fr" unit.

```css
.mygrid
{
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  gap: 2px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.item
{
 
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **grid-template-columns: auto auto;** to fill the entire pink box,

```
.mygrid
{
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 2px;
}
```

View on codepen for more detail : [link](https://codepen.io/Manmohan2301/pen/VwxqmqW)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from `grid-template-columns` property.
You can use the `auto` param  get the same size of columns.
Follow this doc for more information : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

```css
.mygrid
{
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  gap: 2px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.item
{
 
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
</div>
```